# How do I iterate over a SQLite database using the Python API?

Tags: python, sql

Basically I want to be able to choose an amount of numbers using for x...in range(y amount of numbers) and inject them into an SQLite database. However I receive the following error:

```
line 17, in <module>
values (?)""") (number)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

Here is my  non functioning code. All input is appreciated.:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("usernames.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table numbers (number)''')

for number in range(21):
# Insert a row of data
c.execute("""insert into numbers
values (?)"""),(number)

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()
# We can also close the cursor if we are done with it
c.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

execute takes a tuple of values in the case of "?" parameters, so you need to write:

```
c.execute("""insert into numbers values (?)""", (number,))
```

`(number,)` is a way to define a tuple with one element.

And by the way, you can do this more efficiently using the [executemany](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) method:

```
c.executemany(
    """insert into numbers values (?)""",
    [(number,) for number in range(21)]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a misplaced closed paren in `values (?)"""),(number)`.

Not sure why this wasn't a syntax error, though. Is this the exact code that you were using?